# How to support ADB authentication with a MCU?

Tags: rsa, adk

I have developed an embedded application running on Freescale FRDM-KL25Z (Cortex-M0) board to connect Android Phone (HTC Tattoo) via ADB (Android Debug Bridge) protocol.

However Google enforced RSA authentication over USB ADB since v4.2.2 (Jelly bean) to improve security recently. That means my design only supports Android devices from v1.5 to v4.2.1.

During A_CNXN message, an A_AUTH message replied from my Galaxy Nexus to get my RSA (key) as black list.

I can not find enough information regarding all RSA authentication used in ADB interface. Such as key length, key storage locations. I can not find related documentation describing the implement detail.

**It is possible to deploy RSA authentication on an embedded ARM MCU?** So far I found an implementation for LPC1343 (cortex-M3) with limited length integer to RSA calculation (64 bit). However RSA uses at least 512bit in calculation in commercial authentication algorithm.

If no, then I have to change my design to support ADK/AOA with ADK in the same time. But AOA/ADK doesn't support older devices before v2.3.7. It makes things more complex, at least my applications running on Android should be developed in both approaches.

What a mess.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I have evaluted the mbed TLS (mbed-example-tls-benchmark) with STM32F401 (512KB ROM/196KB RAM M4 on 84MHz), its benchmark figure shows RSA2048 can be finished within 2000ms. However it will throw memory malloc error on STM32F103RB (128KB ROM/20KB RAM M3 on 72MHz).

Therefore I draftly concluded, that M3/M4 core can support RSA2048 within acceptable time window, but its memory is a bottleneck. At least we have use 32KB/64KB RAM for RSA/TLS.